# AttributeError: module 'web.views'

Tags: python, backend

archivo views

```python
def productosPorCategoria(request,categoria_id):
        """vista para filtrar productos por categoria"""
        objCategoria = Categoria.objects.get(pk=categoria_id)
        listaProductos = objCategoria.producto_set.all()

        listaCategorias = Categoria.objects.all()
 
        context = {
           'categorias':listaCategorias,
           'productos':listaProductos
        }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

archivo urls

```
path('productosPorCategoria/<int:categoria_id>',views.productosPorCategoria,name='productosPorCategoria'),
```